# String vs. A new Data class

Tags: java, types

I overheard two of my colleagues arguing about whether or not to create a new data model class which only contains one string field and a setter and a getter for it. A program will then create a few objects of the class and put them in an array list. The guy who is storing them argue that there should be a new type while the guy who is getting the data said there is not point going through all this trouble while you can simple store string.

Personally I prefer creating a new type so we know what's being stored in the array list, but I don't have strong arguments to persuade the 'getting' data guy. Do you?

Sarah

Comment: Thanks for the editing Robusto.

Comment: If the alternative is a `String`, I'd strongly recommend making the class immutable with a final field and no setter.

Comment: Does the data type validate the string or perform any manipulation other than straight assignment? Is the value supposed to be mutable? Are the valid valuess known at compile time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ... a new data model class which only contains one string field **and a setter** and a getter for it.

If it was just a getter, then it is not possible to say in general whether a String or a custom class is better.  It depends on things like:

- consistency with the rest of your data model,
- anticipating whether you might want to change the representation,
- anticipating whether you might want to implement validation when creating an instance, add helper methods, etc,
- implications for memory usage or persistence (if they are even relevant).

(Personally, I would be inclined to use a plain String by default, and only use a custom  class if for example, I *knew* that it was likely that a future representation change / refinement would be needed.  In most situations, it is not a huge problem to change a String into custom class later ... if the need arises.)

However, the fact that there is proposed to be a setter for the field changes things significantly.  Instances of the class will be mutable, where instances of String are not.  On the one hand this could possibly be useful; e.g. where you actually need mutability.  On the other hand, mutability would make the class somewhat risky for use in certain contexts; e.g. in sets and as keys in maps.  And in other contexts you may need to copy the instances.  (This would be unnecessary for an immutable wrapper class or a bare String.)

(The simple answer is to get rid of the setter, unless you really need it.)

There is also the issue that the semantics of `equals` will be different for a String and a custom wrapper.  You may therefore need to override `equals` and `hashCode` to get a more intuitive semantic in the custom wrapper case.  (And that relates back to the issue of a setter, and use of the class in collections.)

Comment: Thanks Stephen for the insight about mutability.

Comment: Oops..I meant to vote your post up but in fact voted it down. Will try again in 3 hours!

Answer (score 7):

Wrap it in a class, if it matches the rest of your data model's design.

- It gives you a label for the string so that you can tell what it represents at run time.
- It makes it easier to take your entity and add additional fields, and behavior. (Which can be a likely occurrence>)

That said, the key is *if it matches the rest of your data model's design*... be consistent with what you already have.

Answer (score 4):

Counterpoint to mschaef's answer:

Keep it as a string, if it matches the rest of your data model's design.  (See how the opening sounds so important, even if I temper it with a sentence that basically says we don't know the answer?)

- If you need a label saying what it is, add a comment.  Cost = one line, total.  Heck, for that matter, you need a line (or three) to comment your new class, anyway, so what's the class declaration for?
- If you need to add additional fields later, you can refactor it *then*.  You can't design for everything, and if you tried, you'd end up with a horrible mess.

As [Yegge says](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2007/12/codes-worst-enemy.html), "the worst thing that can happen to a code base is size".  Add a class declaration, a getter, a setter, now call those from everywhere that touches it, and you've added size to your code [without an actual (i.e., non-hypothetical) purpose](http://c2.com/xp/YouArentGonnaNeedIt.html).

Comment: "If you need a label saying what it is, add a comment."

That's only a compile-time label. The benefit of the type is that if I have a reference to x while I'm in a debugger, the formally declared type lets me know what it is at runtime (via the inspector). That can be a useful thing. You can also use something like ReflectionToStringBuilder to get a toString that contains the type name. This can be useful when logging.

@Ken: "(See how the opening sounds so important"

Lead with your 'topic sentence'. This is one of the first things I remember being taught about writing.

Comment: +1 for backing your argument with links. Though (having not read the article but planning to) I have to disagree that a big code base is bad, let alone the worst thing that code happen. As coders we build today on top of structures consisting of millions of lines of code, and we've never had it so good.

Comment: CurtainDog: I'm not surprised to find disagreement with that.  The sentence before the one I quoted is "I happen to hold a hard-won minority opinion about code bases".  :-)

Comment: mschaef: That's a fair point.  I guess I'm used to languages at this level having relatively poor debuggers (i.e., compared to higher-level languages, and especially image-based languages), so I comment and log profusely, anyway, making the class less important.

Comment: mschaef: I wasn't objecting to putting the topic sentence first.  I was noting that the second half of your topic sentence completely negated the first.  :-)  So it sounds as if you're advocating one thing (a new class), when in fact you end up advocating something completely orthogonal (match existing code).

Answer (score 4):

I disagree with the other answers:

> It depends whether there's any real possibility of adding behavior to the type later [[Matthew Flaschen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145575/string-vs-a-new-data-class/3145594#3145594)]

No, it doesn’t. …

> Never hurts to future-proof the design [[Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145575/string-vs-a-new-data-class/3145636#3145636)]

True, but not relevant here …

> Personally, I would be inclined to use a plain String by default [[Stephen C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145575/string-vs-a-new-data-class/3145983#3145983)]

But this isn’t a matter of opinion. It’s a matter of design decisions:

*Is the entity you store logically a string, a piece of text?* If yes, then store a string (ignoring the setter issue).

*If not* – then do **not** store a string. That data may be stored as a string is an **implementation detail**, it should not be reflected in your code.

For the second point it’s irrelevant whether you might want to add behaviour later on. All that matters is that in a strongly typed language, the data type should describe the logical entity. If you handle things that are not text (but may be represented by text, may contain text …) then use a class that internally stores said text. Do not store the text directly.

This is the whole point of abstraction and strong typing: let the types represent the semantics of your code.

And finally:

> As Yegge says, "the worst thing that can happen to a code base is size". [[Ken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145575/string-vs-a-new-data-class/3145717#3145717)]

Well, this is *so* ironic. Have you read any of Steve Yegge’s blog posts? I haven’t, they’re just *too damn long*.

Comment: Konrad - this is all about abstraction boundaries.  Obviously, we need them, *but it is often not a simple question* where they should go, and how strictly they should hide implementation details.  If you don't have enough, you end up with leaky abstractions, or worse.  If you go overboard with putting in abstraction boundaries, you end up with lots of unnecessary code *and* a range of performance issues.  Finally, if you don't see that design decisions are (often) a matter of opinion, you probably need to work on some more technically difficult projects :-)

Comment: @StephenC They are a matter of opinion only insofar as software engineering today is largely voodoo. If we knew more about complex systems we could make better decisions. SE is still in its infancy, a proto-science. But that doesn’t mean that decisions are a matter of opinion, merely that they are ill-informed.

Comment: I think you must have a strange idea of what "a matter of opinion" and "ill-informed" mean.  Also, I think you have an unrealistic expectation of what SE practice *should* be able to achieve; i.e. that there *could* ever be a *single* objectively correct solution to *every* design problem.  (None of the classical engineering disciplines can make this claim either.)

Comment: @StephenC As soon as there are several *qualitatively different* solutions to a problem, one of them is by definition superior to the others. Even if we may never be able to determine the optimal solution analytically, going from there to saying that “it’s a matter of opinion” is fallacious. You can’t pick-and-choose your facts, you can simply acknowledge that you don’t have all the facts and make imperfect (but acceptable) decisions based on imperfect input. This is entirely legitimate, but it’s *not* a matter of opinion.

Comment: @StephenC By the way, I agree that in many cases YAGNI. That is, the plain string is often the appropriate choice (code bloat, and all that). In most cases, when languages don’t offer concise means of expressing this encapsulation, I will also go with a string. But consider languages like Haskell which *does* give you the means. Here the question doesn’t even pose itself; you use a string for text, strongly typed aliases or constructors for everything else.

Comment: *"As soon as there are several qualitatively different solutions to a problem, one of them is by definition superior to the others."* - That assumes that there is an objective scheme for assessing which is superior and that everyone agrees to use that scheme.  It also assumes that the scheme is guaranteed to rank any two solutions so that one is better than the other.  None of these are true in the real world.

Comment: @StephenC It doesn’t assume that. It merely assumes that there is an objective truth which we strive to approximate, even if we may never reach it. You make the distinction between theory and “real world” yet fail to acknowledge that even while we work in an imperfect real world, we can still be *aware* of our metrics’ imperfection. Saying “it’s a matter of preference” is a claim that we *can* make perfect assessments, and find two methods to be really equivalent. This is, as you said yourself, simply not the case.

Comment: Sorry but you are assuming that there is an objective truth AND that different solutions CAN BE OBJECTIVELY RANKED.  You are also assuming that the "perfect world" is even possible.

Comment: “but you are assuming that there is an objective truth” – of course. I’m a scientist. “that different solutions CAN BE OBJECTIVELY RANKED” In principle, yes. Again, of course.

Comment: *"Saying “it’s a matter of preference” is a claim that we can make perfect assessments"* - On the contrary, it is saying that we CAN'T make a perfect assessment.  Instead we have to make assessments based on imperfect information and imperfect (or non-existent) theory, and that those assessments are NECESSARILY subjective.  And no amount of hypothesizing perfect worlds is going to help real software engineers.  (And I might add ... again ... that software engineering is not different to other engineer disciplines in this regard, except to the degree that it is possible to model the unknowns.)

Comment: OK as a scientist I challenge you to prove those assumptions.  Or at least provide plausible evidence for them.  Because if you can't then your argument that good design is "not a matter of opinion" has no logical foundation.

Comment: @Stephen Our disagreement seems to come from different usage of the word “preference”. For me, a preference is the choice between red and blue, or chocolate and ice cream. Qualitatively identical choices. You on the other hand assign it to exactly what I’ve said, making best possible choices in the absence of exact data. If that is so, then the only point we’re disagreeing about is what the word means. Since for me it implies the red-vs-blue choice rather than an engineering decision based on (imperfect) data, I don’t like the word.

Comment: @StephenC (And I do agree, in hindsight, that I was the one who brought “matter of opinion” up, your original formulation is neutral in that regard. I still disagree with the use of stringly typed programming when designing an API, unless YAGNI applies.)

Comment: If you don't like the word "preference", don't use it.  Read back through the answers and comments.  You were the one who introduced it into the conversation ... as an (incorrect) paraphrase of what I was saying.  Note that "matter of opinion" and "matter of preference" do NOT mean the same thing.

Comment: @StephenC I acknowledged that.

Answer (score 2):

It depends whether there's any real possibility of adding behavior to the type later.  Even if the getters and setters are trivial now, a type makes sense if there is a real chance they could do something later.  Otherwise, clear variable names should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

In the time spent discussing whether to wrap it in a class, it could be wrapped and done with. Never hurts to future-proof the design, especially when it only takes minimal effort.

Comment: I agree that they've probably spent more time discussing than it would take to do either way, but I don't agree that it "never hurts" to add more code (which is what this amounts to).  Size is, as Yegge says, code's worst enemy.  A system gets to 100K, 1M, 10M, 100M LOC one line at a time, and before each single one, the developer thought it couldn't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason why the String should be wrapped in a class. The basic perception behind the discussion is, the need of time is a String object. If it gets augmented later, get it refactored then. Why add unnecessary code in the name of future proofing.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping it in a class provides you with more type safety - in your model you can then only use instances of the wrapper class, and you can't easily make a mistake where you put a string that contains something different into the model.

However, it does add overhead, extra complexity and verbosity to your code.